# Regexp_replace "," with "." every other commas in spark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe that instead of `.` it has `,`
and separators of numbers are also comma,
I need to replace only odd comma to dot.
The dataframe is very big but as an example,
I have this:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id |values           |
+---+-----------------+
| 1 | 12,3,10,4,11,5  |
+---+-----------------+
```

I want this df:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id |values           |
+---+-----------------+
| 1 | 12.3,10.4,11.5  |
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: you can split on all `,` and later use pairs `[0:2]`, `[2:4]`, etc. `[n:n+2]` to  create single strings with dot. `for n in range(0, len(list_with_splited_data), 2):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on all commas `,` and later you can use `for`-loop:

1. with `range(0, len(splitted_data), 2)` to create pairs `[0:2]`, `[2:4]`, ..., `[n:n+2]` and join them to strings with dots:

```py
data = '12,3,10,4,11,5'

splitted_data = data.split(',')

new_values = []

for n in range(0, len(splitted_data), 2):
    pair = splitted_data[n:n+2]
    text = '.'.join(pair)

    new_values.append(text)

    print(text)

# -- after loop ---
    
data = ','.join(new_values)

print(data)
```

2. with `iter()` with `zip()` to create pairs and join them to strings with dots:

```py
data = '12,3,10,4,11,5'

splitted_data = data.split(',')

iterator = iter(splitted_data)

new_values = []

for pair in zip(iterator, iterator):
    text = '.'.join(pair)

    new_values.append(text)

    print(text)

# -- after loop ---

data = ','.join(new_values)

print(data)
```

Result:

```
12.3
10.4
11.5
12.3,10.4,11.5
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also use `regex` for this

```
import re

data = '12,3,10,4,11,5'

print(re.sub('(\d+),(\d+)', '\\1.\\2', data))
```

Result:

```
12.3,10.4,11.5
```

Comment: Note, since OP has a pyspark dataframe, the regex will probably have to be applied via udf. I don't think `regexp_replace()` can handle this type of regex.

Comment: @viggnah I don't have `pyspark` so OP will have to check it on his own :)